# Permalink target for recent post

Tags: permalinks

I am trying to set up code to submit a post to StumbleUpon, from my [Rothmania](http://Rothmania.net) site.

The code reads `href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php the_title(); ?>"  alt="" title="">`

and when on a single post view, it pulls the info just fine, offering to submit that particular post. When on the home page, I'd like it to submit the most recent, top post, right now it's loading the last one at the bottom of the page.

Note: this is hand coded, unrelated to the theme, and not using a plugin. Any help here will be appreciated.

Edit -

I now have this code -

```
<?php
$su_link = $su_title = '';

if (is_single()) {
    // We're showing a single blog post
    // => take the data and deal with it
    $su_link = get_permalink();
    $su_title = get_the_title();
} elseif (is_home()) {
    // We're showing the 'home' archive
    // => take the first post's data and deal with it
    $ID = $GLOBALS['posts'][0]->ID;
    $su_link = get_permalink($ID);
    $su_title = get_the_title($ID);
}

if ('' !== $su_link) {
    // We have data
    // => generate the link
    echo '<a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url='.urlencode($su_link).'&title='.urlencode($su_title).'" '
        .'title="'.$su_title.'">'
        .'Link'
        .'</a>';
}
?>

<html>
<head>
  <title>CoffeeCup Image Mapper map file</title>
  <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup Image Mapper">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Created by CoffeeCup Image Mapper (www.coffeecup.com) -->

<!-- Beginning of Client Side Image Map -->
<img src="http://rothmania.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/sociallinks.jpg" USEMAP="#sociallinks" BORDER=0>
<map name="sociallinks">
  <area name="facebook" shape="rect" coords="19,0,76,48" href="https://www.facebook.com/joetaxpayer"  alt="" title="">
  <area name="twitter" shape="rect" coords="73,0,129,48" href="https://twitter.com/JoeTaxpayerBlog"  alt="" title="">
  <area name="stumble" shape="rect" coords="126,0,179,48" href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php the_title(); ?>"  alt="" title="">
  <area name="rss" shape="rect" coords="177,0,243,48" href="http://rothmania.net/feed/"  alt="" title="">
</map>
<!-- End of Client Side Image Map -->
</body>
</html>
```

When I temporarily loaded to the site it offers a 'link' that works perfectly, but I'm staring at this code, not understanding how to link from the proper icon, instead of the word 'link'. 
I appreciate the help here, and yes, I'm in over my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *problem* is that the functions `the_title()`, `the_ID()` etc. access the current post, which is the last post after the query has been handled completely.

Put the following either

- in a text widget, wrapped in `<?php` and `?>`, while having PHP execution enabled for text widgets (e.g., by using [Exec-PHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/) and the like);
- in a [PHP Code Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/) (again wrapped in `<?php` and `?>`);
- hard-coded into your `sidebar.php` (or whatever your *sidebar* template file may be named);
- in your `functions.php`, wrapped in a function, then call the function wherever you want.

#### Share the Most Recent Post

**// EDIT** regarding your last comment:

```
<?php
    $su_link = $su_title = $su_href = '';

    if (is_single()) {
        // We're showing a single blog post
        // => take the data and deal with it
        $su_link = get_permalink();
        $su_title = get_the_title();
    } elseif (is_home()) {
        // We're showing the 'home' archive
        // => take the first post's data and deal with it
        $ID = $GLOBALS['posts'][0]->ID;
        $su_link = get_permalink($ID);
        $su_title = get_the_title($ID);
    }

    if ('' !== $su_link) {
        // We have data
        // => generate the link
        $su_href = 'http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url='.urlencode($su_link).'&title='.urlencode($su_title);
    }
?>


<map name="sociallinks">
    <area name="stumble" shape="rect" coords="126,0,179,48" href="<?php echo $su_href; ?>" title="<?php echo $su_title; ?>" />
</map>
```

Comment: Ok, I'll admit my ignorance. Does this code go in the same spot as the test widget, i.e. the area the images are referenced, etc. or in custom PHP?

Comment: I just updated my answer for you didn't say before that you wanted to use it inside a widget/sidebar. Of course, you can (or even _may have to_) customize the above code. It's a valid starting point, though.

Comment: PERFECT! - There is a special place in Heaven for coders with patience for those of us who are a bit ignorant. This was a fix I'd been seeking for some time now. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_permalink) will accept a post ID or post object, so with a bit of rewriting it should do what you want.

```
$perm = (is_home() && !empty($posts[0])) ? get_permalink($posts[0]) : get_permalink(); 
$title = (is_home() && !empty($posts[0])) ? get_the_title($posts[0]->ID) : get_the_title(); ?>

<a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=<?php echo urlencode($perm); ?>&title=<?php echo urlencode($title); ?>" alt="" title="">test</a>
```

`$posts[0]` should be the first post in the main query. If you have created a secondary query that part could be wrong.